# browsing eeg with mne_browse_raw in python windows

Tags: python, plot

I want to use the seemingly nice *mne* browser but with the python *mne* version on windows. Seems I cannot resort to the C version as it's not supported in windows. I saw a previous post but wanted to ask if there are any updates on this or any way to go around it.